# bash script loses focus when displaying images

Tags: linux, bash, shell, focus

I am trying to figure out how to not lose focus in a shell script while simultaneously displaying an image. User input may come at any time, but seeing the photo taken, would seem important.

To Clarify, I have no problem outputing an image. display works fine, as does animate, and feh, etc.. what i need is for the shellscript to still process user input, (in this example, "t") while displaying the last image taken, for an undefined amount of time.

I'm writing in bash, in Linux.

Heres an example of what I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

capture() {
    cd ~/Desktop/ani
    streamer -c /dev/video0 -s 800x600 -o outfile$i.jpeg
    display outfile$i.jpeg &
    let i++
}   

while true; do
    #clear
    read -rsn1 input

    if [ "$input" = "t" ]; then
           capture
    else
        exit
    fi
done
```

In the actual script I may continue to take photos, so I want to continue listening for user input. I can imagine a couple ways to do this, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: if you want to continue the why put `exit`? means loop will terminate when your condition mismatch.

Comment: exit exits when not t is pressed. This is a simplified example, but the actual interface only has 5 keys (pt56k) so if it reads anything else, i want it to exit, as this represents a serious hardware malfunction.

Answer (score 2):

To continue listening user input. you can do like

```
while true; do
#clear
    read -p "Your input: " input

    if [ "$input" == "t" ]; then
           capture
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather ugly way to solve this: install the utility `wmctrl` (in debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`). Then, after your `display` command, add:

```
sleep 1
wmctrl -i -a "$WINDOWID"
```

This will sleep for one second (to leave some time to the `display` command to finish loading—tune this value to whatever feels right to you). Then, `wmctrl` will use the value of the variable `WINDOWID` (that is hopefully set by your terminal emulator) as a numeric value (`-i`) and raise the window and give it focus (`-a`).